# Datatable draw doesn't clear table and stuck on processing

Tags: javascript, datatables

The table I have created shows data perfectly. However, we have a custom search and we pass the parameters in url and it will return search result. To do that, I made the table.draw with new parameters. The ajax call is correct and coming back with search result however the 'Processing' label is showing and the old rows are there and apparently drawCallback is not being called.

I got no error (apart from 'processing' stuck). I have no idea where to put break point or where to start debugging. Any idea what is possibly causing this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "_Any idea what is possibly causing this problem?_" - without a code example demonstrating what you are doing anything would be a pure guess.

Comment: Thanks David for the commenting. Actually my code consists of columnFactory, columns, datatable wrapper and another js file. That's why I couldn't post a chunk of small code here,

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem is. Datatable sending Draw: 2 to server but server sending back draw: 1 and data table doesn't like that (which is correct).

Comment: But what did you do to fix it?

Comment: @loctrice Just make sure your server data matches with what you expect for columns. Its like one-to-one relationship between data and column

Comment: Thanks in advance Negin.